# File Encoding Issue when opening script that contains Blob

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

When I load a value from file (an image) into a field with datatype Blob, then export it via Admin Tab -> Data Export and open it in an SQL tab i get a File Encoding Problem Message.

> **Unknown File Encoding**   The file  has an unknown
>   character set encoding. Please select the encoding of the file and
>   press OK for Workbench to convert it and open it. Note that as
>   Workbench works with UTF-8 text, if you save back to the original
>   file, its contents will be replaced with the converted data.

Below I can enter a Character Set Encoding Name. When I accept the suggested "Latin1"-Encoding the Image will be corrupted afterwards.

The collation for the schema is utf8 but when I input utf8 in the above mentioned dialog it says

> **Could not Convert Text Data** The file could not be converted from 'UTF-8' to UTF-8: Invalid byte sequence in conversion input.

Answer (score 0):

I had several VARBINARY(16) columns that weren't dumping correctly. I added the line --hex-blob to my mysqldump batch file, along with -r "filename.sql" This fixed things for me. I don't have any other blob types.